# How to filter out the documents based on dynamic keys before using $objectToArray?

Tags: mongodb, filter, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to group based on dynamic keys. So I'm using $objectToArray to query on dynamic keys.

But I need to filter out the documents based on a condition so as to reduce the input going to $objectToArray. Because I have millions of documents and  I just want only a subset of the object fields to be fed to the $objectToArray operator.

> My aim is to get better query performance by reducing the amount of data passed to $objectToArray operator

A sample format of my document structure:

```
[
  {
    "fields": {
      "field_1": {              /* dynamic key */
        "name": "f1",
        "first": {
          "check": true
        }
      },
      "field_2": {             /* dynamic key */
        "name": "f2",
        "second": {
          "check": true
        }
      },
      "description": "abc",
      "summary": {
        "val": "xyz"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "fields": {
      "field_1": {           /* dynamic key */
        "name": "f1",
        "second": {
          "check": false
        }
      },
      "field_2": null,      /* dynamic key */
      "field_3": {         /* dynamic key */
        "name": "f3",
        "second": {
          "check": true
        },
        "first": {
          "check": true
        }
      },
      "description": "lmn",
      "summary": {
        "val": "abc"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I need to filter out the documents before being fed to $objectToArray operator based on the following condition:

1. `fields.<*dynamicKey*>.first` exists
   OR
2. `fields.<*dynamicKey*>.second` exists

Expected output:

```
[
  {
    "fields": {
      "field_1": {
        "name": "f1",
        "first": {
          "check": true
        }
      },
      "field_2": {
        "name": "f2",
        "second": {
          "check": true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "fields": {
      "field_1": {
        "name": "f1",
        "second": {
          "check": false
        }
      },
      "field_3": {
        "name": "f3",
        "second": {
          "check": true
        },
        "first": {
          "check": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

How can I achieve this use case without changing my document structure?

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
I need a stage to filter out documents here
  },
  {
    $project: {
      data: {
        $objectToArray: "$fields"
      }
    }
  }
```

[My aggregation query to group based on dynamic keys can be found here:](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HCVhSz_sWUj)

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

- `$filter` input as array of fields after converting using `$objectToArray` and check condition if first and second's field `check` type is bool (boolean) using `$type`
- convert `fields` array to object using `$arrayToObject`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      fields: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $filter: {
            input: { $objectToArray: "$fields" },
            cond: {
              $or: [
                { $eq: [{ $type: "$$this.v.first.check" }, "bool" ] },
                { $eq: [{ $type: "$$this.v.second.check" }, "bool"] }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/p1jWNjvHt6S)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. My aim is to get better performance by filtering out unwanted fields. But I couldn't see any performance improvement using this approach .It would be great if there is any other method to filter out without using heavy operators like $objectToArray. So that the amount of documents passed to $objectToArray is less.